# Добавить clusterBalloonItemContentLayout для objectManager

Tags: yandex-maps-api

прошу палками сразу не кидать ситуация следующая: 
есть карта с огромным кол-вом меток, есть

```
objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
            clusterize: true,
            gridSize: 64,
            clusterDisableClickZoom: true,
            clusterBalloonContentLayoutWidth: 500,
            clusterBalloonContentLayoutHeight: 350,
            clusterBalloonContentLayout: 'cluster#balloonCarousel',
        });
```

в него добавляю объекты:  objectManager.add(temporyObj)
где заполняется след образом:

```
  var geom = {
    type : 'Point',
    coordinates : [0, 0]
},
prpty = {
    id : <какая то id метки>,
    clusterCaption : <заголовок>
},
opt = {
    preset : 'islands#circleIcon',
    iconColor : ' #EE7737',
    balloonContentLayout : BalloonContentLayout,
    hideIconOnBalloonOpen : false
},
temporyObj ={
    type : 'Feature',
    geometry : geom,
    properties : prpty,
    options : opt
}
```

балун метки собираю через фабрику

```
var BalloonContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
            <html - разметка>, {
                build: function () {
                    BalloonContentLayout.superclass.build.call(this);
                    $('.route-link').bind('click', this.onSetRouteClick);
                },
                clear: function () {
                    $('.route-link').unbind('click', this.onSetRouteClick);
                    BalloonContentLayout.superclass.clear.call(this);
                },

                onSetRouteClick: function () {
                    alert('tntntnt');
                }
            });
```

Подскажите как мне задать балун кластера, на основе балуна метки???

Answer (score 1):

Например, в поле balloon кластера можно отображать balloon первого объекта из этого кластера.  Модифицируя пример из песочницы https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager:

```
function init () {

var ClusterBalloonLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
  '{{ object.features[0].properties.balloonContentBody | raw }}');

var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: [55.76, 37.64],
        zoom: 10
    }, {
        searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
    }),
    objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
        // Чтобы метки начали кластеризоваться, выставляем опцию.
        clusterize: true,
        clusterHasHint: true,
        // ObjectManager принимает те же опции, что и кластеризатор.
        gridSize: 32,
        clusterDisableClickZoom: true,
        clusterHintContentLayout: ClusterHintLayout,
        clusterBalloonContentLayout: ClusterBalloonLayout,
    });

// Чтобы задать опции одиночным объектам и кластерам,
// обратимся к дочерним коллекциям ObjectManager.
objectManager.objects.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenDotIcon');
objectManager.clusters.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenClusterIcons');
myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);

objectManager.add(data);
```